# Gem::InstallError: rack requires Ruby version >= 2.2.2

Tags: ruby

I'm installing Bundle
 `thulehoang@thulehoang-X455LAB:~/workspace/hello_app$ bundle install` but it's not working.

This is error:

`Gem::InstallError: rack requires Ruby version >= 2.2.2.`

`An error occurred while installing rack (2.0.3), and Bundler cannot continue.`
`Make sure that gem install rack -v '2.0.3'  succeeds before bundling.`

Comment: Update rubygems

Comment: `gem install rubygems-update`    
 `update_rubygems`

Comment: I did. But still fail `ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions into the /var/lib/gems/1.9.1 directory.
`

Comment: run with `sudo`